# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I'm having Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my desktop but now I want to upgrade to Xubuntu 16.04. My software updater gave me a 15.10 update but it gave me error of repositories. How to manually update Ubuntu 14.04 to Xubuntu 16.04 without losing any data?

Comment: Backup first then install OS aaa as dual boot ... then install OS BBB to give you triple boot ... checkout guacamole and docker ... boredom gets shunted !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can update from Ubuntu to Xubuntu. But you can simply `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop` to get everything that xubuntu would install.

About your upgrade: (X)Ubuntu 16.04 isn't released yet. You could force the update on the dev version by running `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`.

But since you had to ask that, I would recommend holding off another couple of weeks until it's stable. (and then maybe another couple of weeks while the early adopter update :-))

Comment: I'm actually bored with Ubuntu 14.04 and now would like to taste any other flavor. Tho I'll wait :)

Comment: Then install xubuntu-desktop on your current installation. You can choose your desktop at login.

Comment: After reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenialUpgrades I couldn't figure out how to upgrade Xubuntun from 14.04 to 16.04. Am I missing something? Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Answer (score 0):

If you want Ubuntu's Unity gone for good, and you're absolutely sure you want Xubuntu's Xfce, the best thing you could do is erase Ubuntu 14 and replace it with your preference (Xubuntu).

I tried installing xubuntu-desktop in Ubuntu. It works good, but it is NOT optimised for Ubuntu. You should be aware that every Ubuntu flavor (Xubuntu, Lubuntu, UbuntuMATE, Cubuntu, Kubuntu, etc) it is optimised for its' default desktop environment (aka D.E.) and NOT for any other D.E. Simply installing a different D.E. in any flavor will NOT automatically optimise it for that.

The user experience is just NOT the same: different wallpapers, window styles, cursors, themes,etc. I'm not talking about two different D.E.s, i'm talking about the very same D.E. in two situations: **tweaked** (=better) D.E.- preinstalled and optimisied for its' flavor , and **default** D.E. - installed from repositories (by apt-get install).
There are performance issues too: kernel tweaks not compatible with the D.E will slow everything down, missing or wrong version of libraries, etc